# Build a solution for Kafka+Spark for RDBMS data

Tags: apache-kafka

My current project is in MainFrames with DB2 as its database. We have 70 databases with nearly 60 tables in each of them. Our architect proposed a plan of using Kafka with Spark streaming for processing data. How good is Kafka in reading the RDBMS tables for data ? Do we directly read the data from the tables using Kafka or is there any other way to get the data from RDBMS into Kafka ?
If there is any better solution, your suggestions can help a lot.

Comment: Since it's a database, the data won't get added to it continuously. Maybe like a batch load daily to the database unless I'm missing something. Why not use `sqoop` since it is designed to specifically bring RDBMS data to HDFS?

Comment: I had the same thought as yours. But they said the data will go to peta bytes from next year and Sqoop works slow compared to Kafka with spark. So Im looking solution or a mechanism of how to get the data using Kafka. 
Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Do not directly read from database, it will create additional load.** I would suggest two approaches.

1. Send new data both to databases and to Kafka, or send it to Kafka and then consume for processing.
2. Read data from database write ahead log (I know it is possible for MySQL with [Maxwell](http://maxwells-daemon.io/) but I am not sure for DB2) and send it to Kafka for further processing.

You can use Spark Streaming or [Kafka Streams](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/streams) depending on your needs.

Comment: So, 1. write the data into Kafka cluster along with writing data into RDBMS' 2. From that Kafka library, write a Kafka Producer to produce the data
3. Use Spark streaming to read the data from kafka producer.
Is my understanding correct ?

Comment: You don't read data from producer. Kafka is basically a log. You can use Kafka streams which is library to read data from one topic and write to another. Then consume processed data and write wherever you want, for example to hdfs. Difference between Kafka Streams and Spark Streaming is that latter provides only micro-batching.

Comment: So, basically, you produce data to RDBMS and Kafka. This can be done by Spark Streaming, Flume, or Kafka Connectors. Then youbuse Kafka Streams or Spark Streaming to consume data from Kafka.

Comment: @Sindrartha if you consider my answer as right please mark it :)